# Sums of entire surjective functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

Suppose $(f_n)_n$ is a countable  family of entire, surjective functions, each $f_n:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. Can one always find complex scalars $(a_n)_n$, not all zero,  such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n f_n$ is entire but not-surjective? In fact, I am interested in this question under the additional assumption that $(f_n)_n$ are not polynomials.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are there some extra assumptions on the $f_n$ or on the $a_n$ ? For instance, assume that $f_1=-f_2$, then $a_1=a_2=1$, $a_n=0$, $n\geq 3$, will yield $\sum a_nf_n=0$...

Comment: @M.Dus: I suppose OP asks whether one can *always* find such scalaras. I also guess that the sum is supposed to be entire, not surjective *and non-constant*.

Comment: @Mateusz Kwasnicki: this does not help. Suppose they are all polynomials. If the linear combination is not constant is must be surjective.

Comment: Maybe $(f_n)$ denotes an infinite sequence of functions?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko   I made some edits, I hope it is more clear now. Indeed, the question is if this is true for any such family.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One expects there to be no such $a_n$ in general, because the
"typical" entire functions is surjective (those that aren't are of the 
special form $z \mapsto c + \exp g(z)$).  An explicit example is
$f_n(z) = \cos z/n$: any convergent linear combination $f = \sum_n a_n f_n$ 
is of order $1$, so if $f$ is not surjective then $g$ is a polynomial
of degree at most $1$; but $f$ is even, so must be constant,
from which it soon follows that $a_n=0$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. If something does not hold for polynomials, don't expect that it will hold for entire functions:-)

For example, all non-constant functions of order less than $1/2$ are surjective.
This follows from an old theorem of Wiman that for such function $f$ there exists
a sequence $r_k\to\infty$ such that $\min_{|z|=r_k}|f(z)|\to\infty$ as $k\to \infty.$
And of course linear combinations of functions of order less than $1/2$ are of order less
than $1/2$.

Edit. To construct a counterexample with infinite sums, one can use lacunary series. Let $\Lambda$ be a sequence of integers $n_k$ which grows sufficiently fast,
for example, such that $n_k/k\to\infty$,
and consider the class of entire functions of the form
$$f(z)=\sum_{n\in\Lambda}c_nz^n.$$
It is known that all such functions are surjective. And of course any linear combination of such functions, finite or infinite, belongs to the class.

Reference: L. Sons, An analogue of a theorem of W.H.J. Fuchs on gap series,
Proc. LMS, 1970, 21 525-539.

Comment: Didn't the OP ask about *infinite* sums? The exponential function is the sum of its power series, and it is not surjective, so if $f_n(z) = z^n$, the answer is *yes*.

Comment: Do we really need a theorem of Wiman (or anyone else) to verify your claim that non-constant functions $f$ of order $<1$ are surjective? Doesn't this just follow from the Hadamard factorization, which implies that if $f-c$ doesn't have a zero, then $f-c\equiv d$.

Comment: @Christian Remling: Hadamard factorization is fine of course. On my opinion, Wiman's theorem is somewhat simpler, but this is a question of opinion.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: Ok, thanks. I was just thinking that everyone knowns Hadamard factorization while you are probably the only one who is familiar with Wiman's theorem, but of course it doesn't matter...

Comment: @Christian Remling: I agree  with the first part ("everyone...") but the second part ("only one...") is certainly an exaggeration:-)